# How can I compile CoffeeScript from .NET using Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, .net, coffeescript, visual-studio-2022

I want to write an `HttpHandler` that compiles CoffeeScript code on-the-fly and sends the resulting JavaScript code.

How can CoffeeScript be compiled in .NET?

Previously I was using Mindscape Web Workbench but it only supports Visual Studio versions 2010-2013. I need this for Visual Studio 2022.